# Как получить к явной реализации интерфейса в базовом классе из класса наследника

Tags: c#, .net

Базовый класс определен в библиотеке и изменить его я не могу. 
Мне нужно переопределить в наследнике метод базового класса, являющийся явной реализацией интерфейса (DoAction в примере), а потом вызвать сам метод из базового класса. И если с первым проблем вроде не возникает, то вот вызвать метод, определенный в базовом классе не получается.

```
public interface ICanDoAction
{
    void DoAction();
}


public class Parent: ICanDoAction
{
    void ICanDoAction.DoAction()
    {
    }

}


public class Parent: ICanDoAction
{
    void ICanDoAction.DoAction()
    {
    }
}


public class Child: Parent, ICanDoAction
{
    void ICanDoAction.DoAction()
    {
        /* Мой код */
        /* Нужно вызвать ISample.DoAction из базового класса */
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976216/how-to-call-an-explicitly-implemented-interface-method-on-the-base-class

Comment: Попахивает плохой архитектурой. Не используйте наследование для избежания дублирования кода, используйте паттерн Стратегия или агрегацию.